# Multiple isolated browsers on a single machine

Tags: browsers, browser-session

First of all - sorry if it's something well-known amongst testers, I'm not a tester at all but for now I must perform some kind of tests.

We have a distributed software layer distributed across different regions. Thus, we have to test how it works on different IPs (countries), and to check how it returns cookies and even images (just a country flag).

We don't need headless solutions such as phantomjs - in fact, that's just a simple thing and it's enough to test it manually (in other words - nobody gave us resources for writing normal tests).

We can use proxies to emulate different IPs.

How to run multiple browsers on a single machine? Each browser must be isolated from the others - that means, no shared cookies, cache, passwords or anything else. Also, at the same time, each browser must have unique proxy settings.

Firefox, Chrome, Opera or anything else - doesn't matter.

This should be executed on a linux OS (Ubuntu or Debian preferable).

P.S. Multiple virtual machines seem to be an overkill in this situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install multiplecinstances of Mozilla on Linux if you do the install manuakky (don.t use apt-get it will complain).

1. Download and unpack the tarball
2. Create a new firefox profile

   firefox -CreateProfile "firefox-9.0.1 /home/bob/.mozilla/firefox/firefox-9.0.1"
3. Launch firefox from CLI where you can specify profiles.

   /home/bob/firefox-9.0.1/firefox -P firefox-9.0.1

Note: You may be able to use one FF install with different profiles to achieve your objective but I'm not certain as I've not tried.

Comment: thanks - but will it isolate their caches as well? just want to make it clear

Comment: @Spaceman - it should isolate the caches as these are generally stored with the profile rather than with the application. If each install has a separate application directory, the caches will definitely be isolated.